# What is the difference between pygame.Rect() and pygame.draw.rect()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pygame-surface, pygame2

I was learning to create a simple Pygame window which displays a Rectangle. I watched two different videos on Youtube. One of the Youtuber  used Pygame.draw.rect() to create a rectangle whereas other Youtuber used both pygame.Rect() and Pygame.draw.rect(). Both gave same result at the end. So what is the difference between these two codes??

Comment: Pretty much none, as per timeit(the timing module) pygame.draw.rect() is 0.97 ms slower than pygame.rect(), or atleast on my PC core i5 7200u cpu

Comment: @AryanMishra Sorry, but this is wrong. Read the answer

Answer (score 3):

[`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) is a class whose instances represent rectangular areas.

[`pygame.draw.rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect) is a function that draws rectangles. One of its arguments is a `pygame.Rect` instance representing the rectangle to draw.

They are completely different things.

Answer (score 3):

`pygame.Rect` creates a `Rect` instance to be passed into `pygame.draw.rect`. Consider this short snippet:

For anyone else who is reading this, first install `pygame` by running `pip install pygame` in your IDE's terminal or your default operating system's terminal.

```py
import pygame
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))

while True:
    pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, 'white', (30, 30, 100, 100))
    pygame.display.update()
```

The tuple that we passed in to `pygame.draw.rect` consists of `(x, y, width, height)`:

- `x` being where our rectangle will sit on the vertical axis
- `y` being where our rectangle will sit on the horizontal axis
- `width` being the width of our rectangle
- `height` being the height of our rectangle

This is how you would use `pygame.draw.rect` by itself. Behind the scenes, `pygame` transforms this tuple into a `pygame.Rect` object. So you are only doing a bit more work when using `pygame.Rect`. For example:

```py
pygame_rect_object = pygame.Rect(30, 30, 100, 100)
pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, 'white', pygame_rect_object)
```

As you can see, creating a `pygame.Rect` object is the same as passing the tuple. A few advantages are readability, and you can pass it into multiple `pygame.draw.rect` functions without having to repeat the tuple.

Hope this has helped!!!

Answer (score 0):

Too many "rects" here for a newbie...  How about:

```py
my_rectangle = pygame.Rect(30, 30, 100, 100)          #create rectangle object
pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, 'white', my_rectangle)       #put it on the screen after
                                                      #you "flip" the screen
```